# Android/NFC: read ATR from Smartcard (EMV)

Tags: android, nfc, emv

I got an EMV Smartcard wich I want to communicate with with my Mobile phone.
The communication itself works without problems via IsoDep, but I can't figure out how I can get the ATR.
As far as I know the intent should contain the ATR, can someone please tell me the code I need therefore?

Or if this is not possible maybe someone knows how to warm reset the card with a command like SELECT where the answer is the ATR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contactless cards do not have an ATR. You may be interested in the historical bytes of the ATS (Answer to Select), though. You can retrieve these by calling [`getHistoricalBytes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#getHistoricalBytes%28%29):

```
Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
IsoDep iso = IsoDep.get(tag);
NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);
if (nfcA == null || iso == null)
   return; // not an IsoDep+NfcA tag
byte[] histBytes = iso.getHistoricalBytes();
...
```

Keep in mind that this only works for ISO 14443 Type A tags (`NfcA`). For Type B tags (`NfcB`), you may want to investigate [`getHiLayerResponse()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#getHiLayerResponse%28@%29).

Comment: What is the purpose of the ATR? How does it relate to the hilayer response? Would it allow me to access more data from the card?

Comment: This works well on most devices except LG - so far I haven't be able to find a solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

Contactless card do return ATR. However, you can't get ATR from current android NFC API. Android NFC API only returns historical bytes from ATR.

The reason that contactless card do return ATR:
Please note that ATR is 7816 Answer to reset. The reader (nfc phone in this case) talks to smart cards using ISO 7816 (T=CL) APDU exchange, which is transported via contactless interface ISO 14443-4. Since there is ISO 7816 in this case, you will get ATR.

Comment: Contactless cards do **NOT** provide a real ATR (answer-to-reset) as they do not undergo the ISO 7816-3 reset procedure. (Though cards may contain a EF.ATR file containing the data normally contained in an ATR.) T=CL (which is basically the transport protocol defined in *ISO 14443-4*) has an ATS (answer-to-select) for type A (which comes close to an ATR as in that it also contains historical bytes) and an answer-to-ATTRIB for type B (that's where the data for `getHiLayerResponse()` comes from).

Comment: I can get ATR from contactless card using SCM reader from both A & B card. It may not be 'real' in traditional sense as you pointed out. 
However, it does return ATR.

Comment: Well, the card does not return that ATR. Instead what you see is a pseudo-ATR generated by the PC/SC driver that connect your smartcard reader to applications. The pseudo-ATR (**not** generated or "returned" by the card) is used to pass (otherwise inaccesible) information about the contactless protocol to the application layer. As Android does not use PC/SC for access to smartcards through NFC there is also **no** ATR involved here.

Comment: @MichaelRoland

if contactless cards does not return ATR and pseudo-ATR is used to pass information about contactless protocol then what information I can get?
As I read in ISO 7816, if cards support extended length it should be store in ATR, but if that ATR is not not real returned by card then how can i get such kind of information.

Comment: I have 2 cards (type A and B). With type A, I can get historical bytes by calling byte[] histBytes = iso.getHistoricalBytes(). I checked by using a card reader, this historical bytes are correct. But with type B,  iso.getHiLayerResponse() return empty, although card reader does return ATR of this card. Do you have any idea about this .

Comment: @neo Please ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of hijacking this comment thread.